# Android, recyclerview not updating list

Tags: android, list, android-recyclerview, alarm

I have a recyclerview with rows, the datasource of the recyclerview is a List. An alarm object contains a getTime() & setTime(...)
I have an RecyclerItemClick handler, so I know which element in which row I click.

In my onclick for the time I do this:

```
        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
            new RecyclerItemClickListener(getContext(), recyclerView ,new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override public void onItemClick(View view, final int position) {
                    String elementID;
                    try
                    {
                        elementID = view.getResources().getResourceName(view.getId());
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        elementID = "row";
                    }
                    if (elementID.contains("btnRemove"))
                    {
                        alarmList.remove(position);
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    if (elementID.contains("clockTime"))
                    {
                        //Set time click action
                        Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                        int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                        int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                        TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
                        mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(getContext(), new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                                final Alarm alarmToUpdate = mAdapter.alarmsList.get(position);
                                alarmToUpdate.setTime(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                                mAdapter.RemoveAlarm(position);
                                mAdapter.alarmsList.clear();
                                mAdapter.AddAlarm(position, alarmToUpdate);
                                //mAdapter.alarmsList.get(position).setTime(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                                Log.d(TAG, "pos: " + position + " & "+ mAdapter.alarmsList.get(position).getTime());
                                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            }
                        }, hour, minute, true);//Yes 24 hour time
                        mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
                        mTimePicker.show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //
                    }
                }

                @Override public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    // do whatever
                }
            })
    );
```

As you can see I call my adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(),
but the time is not changing.
my Log.d result shows me that my alarmList gets updated. I can also remove an alarm (the onclick above it), and alarmsList.clear() is also working.

Update: 
Implemented suggested solutions, removed local alarmlist to make code cleaner.
Also replaced TimeClock with a "normal" textview to make sure the problem isn't in there.
result: still no updated recyclerview, log.d shows that my list is updated :(.

my adapter:
(now with a public list temporary)

```
public class AlarmsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AlarmsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

// make this private, find best way to update alarms.
public List<Alarm> alarmsList = new ArrayList<Alarm>();

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView time;
    public TextView days;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.clockTime);
        days = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.days);
    }
}


public AlarmsAdapter() {
    //
}

public void AddAlarm(Alarm alarm) {
    alarmsList.add(alarm);
}

public void AddAlarm(int position, Alarm alarm) {
    alarmsList.add(position, alarm);
}

public void RemoveAlarm(int position) {
    alarmsList.remove(position);
}

public void UpdateAlarm(Alarm alarm) {
    this.alarmsList = alarmsList;
}


@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.timer_row, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //Log.d(TAG, "inBindViewHolder");
    //Alarm alarm = alarmsList.get(position);
    //holder.time.setFormat24Hour("04:20");
    //holder.time.setText("04:20");
    //holder.days.setText("mon, tue");
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return alarmsList.size();
}
```

}

Comment: I need to see adapter class

Comment: first set adapter again like following 
mAdapter.AlarmsAdapter(alarmsList);
then do mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Can't call the constructor again, but I see where you are going, Im only adding/updating my local alarmlist.

Comment: create one method inside adapter and set the list again

Comment: alarmList.remove(position);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

this works, so the problem is in the editing instead of removing part :p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I wasn't updating my view -_- 
I called AlarmsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() and in AlarmsAdapter.onBindViewHolde(...) you have to update the view.

Now I do this and it works:

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //Log.d(TAG, "inBindViewHolder");
    Alarm alarm = alarmsList.get(position);
    holder.time.setText(alarm.getTime());
    holder.days.setText(alarm.getDays());
}
```

Thank you all for helping me find out my stupidity :)

Answer (score 2):

create the methode to refresh the data set suppose method name is setDat

`mAdapter.setData(alarmsList);`

then do

`mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Isn't working. I updated my code in my question, and deleting is working, so I'm working with the right list.

Comment: do alarmsList.clear(); then add then notifydatasetchange

Comment: that works!  but then i tried to copy the listElement I want to update, then remove it from list, and push my copy.atPosition, but that doesnt work. 
so removing works, clearing works, but updating not :(

Comment: did you find your answer ?